# M-to-M relation MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding a query in MySQL. 
I have 2 tables `Products` and `Users` and 1 table in between to map them to one another `Users_Products`.
I would like to select all products + specific user's relation to all the products using the `Users_Products` table.

Products

- id
- name

Users

- id
- name

Users_Products

- user_id
- product_id

Surely i can do `SELECT * FROM Products` and then `SELECT * FROM  Users_Products WHERE user_id=1` and then map them using a double for loop. I was just wondering if this is possible with 1 query or if I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: I suggest you learn some SQL basics before attempting to mess around with the database.  This is like one of the simplest think you can do with a database.  Just JOIN all 3 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join all tables and filter by user_id. This query returns all products that belong to user.id = 1

```
select
from   products p
join   user_products up
on     p.id = up.product_id
join   users u
on     u.id = up.user_id
where  u.id = 1;
```